# Building and traversing Huffman code tree in python3.x

Tags: python, tree, python-3.3

I am working on something related to Huffman Encoding.  I am trying to create a Huffman code tree using a heap from an input file, let's call it **counts.txt**.  I have taken care of reading in that file and storing a list of tuples containing 2 integers called **frequencies**.

**frequencies** looks like

```
[(int, int), (int, int), (int, int), (int, int), (int, int), (int, int)]
```

but much longer.  I have never built a Huffman code tree so I am entering new water and I have looked at Huffman code but it overwhelms me.  I have made a few methods in an attempt to built that tree and then I will try to traverse it but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  Here is that I have right now and I believe the mistake lies here as this is the part I don't understand well:

How exactly do you build and then view a Huffman tree so that you can view/debug it, and what am I doing wrong?  Like I said I have never actually used a Huffman code tree before, or really built any tree for that matter so I will acknowledge I am a total novice.  Any help anybody could provide me in sending me in the right direction or offering a second opinion on this intimidating mess of code I have here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Keep at it :-) Huffman trees are cool, and conceptually pretty simple, but the algorithms to build one are not very obvious (to me, anyway). Some links which may help: [one](http://cbloomrants.blogspot.com/2010/07/07-02-10-length-limitted-huffman-codes.html), [two](http://cbloomrants.blogspot.com/2010/07/07-03-10-length-limitted-huffman-codes.html), and especially [three](http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/~alistair/inplace.c).

Comment: @Cameron is that java? Is it the same for python?

Comment: It's C. The algorithm is language-independent, but the code is certainly not compatible with Python.

Comment: @Cameron With respect to my code, do you think I should implement it differently?  I am unfamiliar with C.